# Make scroll bar scroll from top to bottom in TextArea JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scroll, textarea

How can I make TextArea to scroll from top to bottom instead of from left to right? I have no idea how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textArea.setWrapText(true);
```

> If a run of text exceeds the width of the TextArea, then this variable
>   indicates whether the text should wrap onto another line

And when you have many lines that cant be all visible in current view  height you gonna get vertical scroll available , and you can scroll up and down.